# Is the Heatvision spell dependent on regular vision?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, vision-and-light, special-senses

The 3rd-rank *[Heatvision](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1358)* spell from *Rage of Elements* gives a willing creature 60 feet of infrared vision as a precise sense. The spell is called Heat**vision**, the sense is gives is called infrared **vision**, and the spell description mentions how the target **visually** senses heat energy, but I can't find any rules that confirm or deny if this spell is dependent on vision as a precise sense, and if the effects persist if the target's vision is compromised.

The specific rules interaction I'm confused about is with the [dazzled](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=65) condition, which makes everything concealed from you if vision is your only precise sense, and the [blinded](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=59) condition, which grants a penalty to Perception checks if vision is your only precise sense. While it seems like precise infrared vision bypasses these effects, I'm still not sure if it would actually work, partially because it doesn't make much logical sense to me that a blinded creature can still "visually sense" infrared light.

Answer (score 2):

## Heatvision is not dependent on your regular vision, but is affected by things that affect vision

There is nothing in any of the rules that state that Heatvision requires any form of vision already, or that they have any form of eyes to see with etc. However, it does grant a form of vision and as a result is effected by the conditions listed.

Heatvision specifies:

> ... This vision can detect any...

The two effects specify:

Blinded:

> You can't detect anything using vision.

Dazzled:

> ...If vision is your only precise sense,...

Though Precise Sense mentions "average vision" without clarification, there are precise senses that make no mention of a form of vision, such as [Tremor Sense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=2413) which would imply "vision" would cover Heat vision here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that it doesn't rely on the creature's eyes specifically, but could still be affected by things that cause blinded/dazzled with the relevant flat checks? What if the creature is already blinded permanently, such as from the [*blindness*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1453) spell?

Comment: @Ifusaso According to the rules: blinded just effects vision, which heatvision is ergo blinded effects things that use heatvision. 
You may choose to change this with houserules (though this will change balance, likely for the worst).